# Disable customizer control sorting within sections

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a huge Theme Customizer with more than 3000 controls and I'm using jQuery UI to group and style them. The thing is that Wordpress destroys my Customizer UI when it sorts controls within sections and I need to disable (unbind) this.

I need to unbind this part:

`$( [ api.panel, api.section, api.control ] ).each( function ( i, values ) {
    var debouncedReflowPaneContents = _.debounce( api.reflowPaneContents, api.settings.timeouts.reflowPaneContents );
    values.bind( 'add', debouncedReflowPaneContents );
    values.bind( 'change', debouncedReflowPaneContents );
    values.bind( 'remove', debouncedReflowPaneContents );
} );`

I need to override this code from my custom javaSript file which is responsible for Customizer UI. I know that if I increase "api.settings.timeouts.reflowPaneContents" time or if I unbind "values.bind( 'add', debouncedReflowPaneContents );" this will help but I don't know how to do this.

This is URGENT. Please help!

Regards, Duke

Comment: Is there anyone able to help me?

Comment: Would be great if you can share the customizer code so we can preview?

Comment: You don't actually need theme customizer code. I just need to unbind given code, which is bound from: wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js

Comment: ok, more than 3000 controls looks amazing, maybe you cannot share the controls, but what is the solution what you are using?

Comment: I will provide some general feedback answer.

Comment: In what file you have `[ api.panel, api.section, api.control ]` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in the code is Backbone.js that goes together with Underscore.js.

The `api.panel, api.section, api.control` are collections

```
$( [ api.panel, api.section, api.control ] ).each( function ( i, values ) {
    var debouncedReflowPaneContents = _.debounce( api.reflowPaneContents, api.settings.timeouts.reflowPaneContents );
    values.bind( 'add', debouncedReflowPaneContents );
    values.bind( 'change', debouncedReflowPaneContents );
    values.bind( 'remove', debouncedReflowPaneContents );
} );
```

And `bind` is actually Backbone event `bind`, not jQuery.
jQuery `bind` is for DOM, and Backbone `bind` is for the Backbone object model.

All you can do is to check the [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/) and `remove` looks what you need to do, but it would need more time and code shared to understand the removal.

`api` means you are under certain function closure and typically this means `wp.customize`

You haven't yet shared the details where you have `[ api.panel, api.section, api.control ]`, I would not guess.

Take this and accept this as a most helpful answer. You can easily reset the accept later if someone provides a better one.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this and let you know if this does a trick.

Comment: Note that the Backbone `bind` here is not actually Backbone. The customizer implements its own Backbone-like JS framework. There is a `wp.customize.Events` mixin that defines `bind` and `unbind` and `trigger`.

Comment: Thanks @WestonRuter. I was not aware of this fact.

Comment: @prosti Please search for "// Sort the controls within each section" in the wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js, the code under that comment removes customizer controls withing section and then appends them back to the same section with another order. At that moment my controls, which are wrapped in, lets say, one "<div>" are out from there and UI is destroyed. Does this makes sense?